# How can I install/access 'base64url-encode-string' and 'base64url-encode-region' for emacs 26.1?

Tags: character-encoding, install

My CentOS 8 Stream comes with emacs-26.1 which does not have 'base64url-encode-region'.  It seems like this came out in emacs-27.x.

I'd like to have the functionality as painlessly as possible.

I looked in the MELPA and GNU packages to the extent that I knew how, and nothing jumped out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does [this](https://gist.github.com/inouetmhr/4116307) help?

Comment: Thanks!  Can I just plop these lines into my `.emacs` file?  I haven't added a `.el` file since emacs-18 (4.2 BSD).

Comment: Yes - it's just function definitions. OTOH, whether they work or not is another matter :-)

Comment: From what I can tell, it would work if `base64-encode-string` were defined.  It's not.  I think someone who can work (safely) with elisp could make this work for `base64-encode-region`.